# CSS positioning of tooltip breaks inside modal popup

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip, positioning, modal-dialog

I'm using the OSX style "simple modal" with the tipTip tooltip (both jquery).

My problem: The tooltip works great inside the modal popup when opened up for the first time, but when closed and reoponed, it goes off to the top left corner.

Example: http://drawnigh.org/site/new/modal/

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: I am also facing this same problem in my own tool tip implementation. I am awaiting for any answers.

Comment: See answer below, worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - **DEMO:** https://so.lucafilosofi.com/css-positioning-of-tooltip-breaks-inside-modal-popup/

make sure the tip load after the modal animation is done this way:

open the osx.js find this piece of code and add the tip call like below:

```
    open: function (d) {
        var self = this;
        self.container = d.container[0];
        d.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
            $("#osx-modal-content", self.container).show();
            var title = $("#osx-modal-title", self.container);
            title.show();
            d.container.slideDown('slow', function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var h = $("#osx-modal-data", self.container).height()
                        + title.height()
                        + 20; // padding
                    d.container.animate(
                        {height: h}, 
                        200,
                        function () {
                            $("div.close", self.container).show();
                            $("#osx-modal-data", self.container).show();
                            // add this line of code...
                            $("form input").tipTip({defaultPosition: "right", activation: "focus", delay: "10", fadeIn: 1});
                        }
                    );
                }, 300);
            });
        })
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest changing the position attribute of #tiptip_holder to fixed. With absolute positioning the tooltip won't move down with the modal popup when the page is scrolled.